# How to remove all links from an html content

Tags: javascript

Say I have an html content like,

```
<p id="p_content">
Test

<a href='https://google.com'>google</a>

Test

<a href='https://example.co'>example</a>

Hello

<a href='https://Test.com'>test</a>

</p>
```

How to remove all links from this. I tried like,

```
var content = document.querySelector('#p_content');
var a = content.querySelectorAll('a');
var texts = [].slice.call(a).map(function(val){
   return val.innerHTML;
});
console.log(texts);
document.querySelector('#p_content').innerHTML = texts;
```

It doesnt return any value but an empty object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `remove()`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#p_content a').forEach(el => el.remove())
```

```html
<p id="p_content">
  Test
  <a href='https://google.com'>google</a>
  Test
  <a href='https://example.co'>example</a>
  Hello
  <a href='https://Test.com'>test</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a"); // Select your links
links.forEach((link) => { // loop through them
  link.parentElement.removeChild(link); // find their parent element, then remove them
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An example to remove all the links from HTML Dom using [while loop](https://javascriptcode.org/javascript-while-loop/) and Element.remove() method

```
const links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
while ( links.length > 0 ) {
    links[0].remove(); 
}
```

Reference - [Remove all links from document using JavaScript](https://javascriptcode.org/javascript-html-dom-remove-all-the-links/)